# Azure Data Factory - run script on parquet files and output as parquet files

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory I have a pipeline, created from the built-in copy data task, that copies data from 12 entities (campaign, lead, contact etc.) from Dynamics CRM (using a linked service) and outputs the contents as parquet files in account storage. This is run every day, into a folder structure based on the date. The output structure in the container looks something like this:

- Raw/CRM/2022/05/28/campaign.parquet
- Raw/CRM/2022/05/28/lead.parquet
- Raw/CRM/2022/05/29/campaign.parquet
- Raw/CRM/2022/05/29/lead.parquet

That's just an example, but there is a folder structure for every year/month/day that the pipeline runs, and a parquet file for each of the 12 entities I'm retrieving.

This involved creating a pipeline, dataset for the source and dataset for the target. I modified the pipeline to add the pipeline's run date/time as a column in the parquet files, called RowStartDate (which I'll need in the next stage of processing)

My next step is to process the data into a staging area, which I'd like to output to a different folder in my container. My plan was to create 12 scripts (one for campaigns, one for leads, one for contact etc.) that essentially does the following:

- accesses all of the correct files, using a wildcard path along the lines of: Raw/CRM/ * / * / * /campaign.parquet
- selects the columns that I need
- Rename column headings
- in some cases, just take the most recent data (using the RowStartDate)
- in some cases, create a slowly changing dimension, ensuring every row has a RowEndDate

I made some progress figuring out how to do this in SQL, by running a query using OPENROWSET with wildcards in the path as per above - but I don't think I can use my SQL script in ADF to move/process the data into a separate folder in my container.

My question is, how can I do this (preferably in ADF pipelines):

1. for each of my 12 entities, access each occurrence in the container with some sort of Raw/CRM/*/*/*/campaign.parquet statement
2. Process it as per the logic I've described above - a script of some sort
3. Output the contents back to a different folder in my container (each script would produce 1 output)

I've tried:

- Using Azure Data Factory, but when I tell it which dataset to use, I point it to the dataset I created in my original pipeline - but this dataset has all 12 entities in the dataset and the data flow activity produces the error: "No value provided for Parameter 'cw_fileName" - but I don't see any place when configuring the data flow to specify a parameter (its not under source settings, source options, projection, optimize or inspect)
- using Azure Data Factory, tried to add a script - but in trying to connect to my SQL script in Synapse - I don't know my Service Principal Key for the synapse workspace
- using a notebook Databricks, I tried to mount my container but got an error along the lines that "adding secret to Databricks scope doesn't work in Standard Tier" so couldn't proceed
- using Synapse, but as expected, it wants things in SQL whereas I'm trying to keep things in a container for now.

Could anybody point me in the right direction. What's the best approach that I should take? And if its one that I've described above, how do I go about getting past the issue I've described?

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) Can you clarify what you mean by "Synapse wants things in SQL"? Synapse is very diverse and supports SQL, Storage, and Notebooks. 2) Data Flows absolutely have parameters, as do data sets. Your pipeline activity must supply the value if either are declared. 3) A Spark notebook in Synapse would be another option. For Notebooks in particular, you may want to consider using HDFS style path names such as "Raw/CRM/Year=2022/Month=05/Day=28/campaign.parquet".

Comment: @JoelCochran 1) - I mean that of the few things I've tried, it seems to require a SQL Pool, which I was hoping to avoid for these types of data transformation (going from "Raw files" - i.e. direct copies from a source system to "Staging" files - also to be stored as parquet). Perhaps, as per your point 3, using a spark notebook is the best choice? 2) Thanks, I've found the parameter settings. 3) I will try a Spark Notebook

Comment: We get along quite well with no Dedicated SQL Pools. It sometimes requires thinking about problems in different ways, but they definitely aren't required.

Comment: @DaarioNaharis, How did you finally achieve it?

One of the ways we've got this to work is by running a CETAS command which in turn creates a new parquet file containing the "altered" dataset.

In our case, we needed an external table for downstream processing, but I've seen people using CETAS command just for the sake of this new parquet file creation and then deleting the external table. Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `data flow` dataset parameter values from the pipeline `data flow` activity settings.

[image]